# Pyspark: Convert list to list of lists

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In a pyspark dataframe, I have a column which has list values, for example: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

I would like to convert the above as `[[1,2,3,4] , [5,6,7,8]]` given 4 for every column value.

Please let me know, how can I achieve this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` function as shown below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],)], ['values'])

df.selectExpr("transform(sequence(1, size(values), 4), v-> slice(values, v, 4)) as values")\
    .show(truncate=False)

+----------------------------+
|values                      |
+----------------------------+
|[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]|
+----------------------------+
```